# How can I manipulate this JSON response obtained by RestTemplate to set a DTO object?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-resttemplate, spring-json

I am working on a Spring Boot application and I have the following problem. I have to set values of a simple DTO object from the JSON output retrieved from a REST call.

Basically I am calling this **GET** API: https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=ethereum&vs_currencies=eur

As you can see it return a JSON response like this:

```
{
    "ethereum": {
        "eur": 2509.13
    }
}
```

So I have this **CoingeckoPriceDTO** class:

@Getter

```
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CoingeckoPriceDTO {
    
    String coin;
    BigDecimal price;
    
}
```

And then I have this service method:

```
@Service
@Log
public class CoingeckoInfoServiceImpl implements CoingeckoInfoService {
    
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    String coinPriceApiUrl = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids={coinName}&vs_currencies={targetCurrency}";
    
    
    @Override
    public CoingeckoPriceDTO getCoinPrice(String coinName, String targetCurrency) {
        
        CoingeckoPriceDTO result = new CoingeckoPriceDTO();
        
        String completeUrl = this.coinPriceApiUrl.replace("{coinName}", coinName).replace("{targetCurrency}", targetCurrency);
        
        log.info("completeUrl: " + completeUrl);
        
        String responseStr = this.restTemplate.getForObject(completeUrl, String.class);
        
        log.info("responseStr: " + responseStr);
        
        
        return result;
    }
    
}
```

It simply perform the call via **REST** template then it print it as a string, and infact it print this string containing the expected JSON response as string:

```
responseStr: {"ethereum":{"eur":2499.04}}
```

Now my problem is to put these values into the previous **CoingeckoPriceDTO** fields. I think that I need to do some JSON manipulation to do it:

In particular I have to set my DTO **String coin** field with the **ethereum** string retrieved by the returned JSON (note that this is not the field value but it is the field name. I have no idea how to keep it and put it into my DTO object field). Then I have to set my DTO **BigDecimal price** field with the **eur** value in the JSON.

How can I implement a behavior like this?

Comment: Dont read response string. Read it as POJO, then you can transform one pojo to your required one. No direct json manipulation whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try to change your class to something like this:

```
   public class CoingeckoPriceDTO {

        private String coin;

        @JsonAlias({"eur", "dol", "sek", "etc"})
        private BigDecimal price;

        public String getCoin() {
            return coin;
        }

        public void setCoin(String coin) {
            this.coin = coin;
        }

        public BigDecimal getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
            this.price = price;
        }
    }
```

Add to the @JsonAlias any currencies you intend to include.

And proceed to doing something like this:

```
public CoingeckoPriceDTO getCoinPrice(String coinName, String targetCurrency) throws JsonProcessingException {
    String completeUrl = coinPriceApiUrl.replace("{coinName}", coinName).replace("{targetCurrency}", targetCurrency);
    String responseStr = this.restTemplate.getForObject(completeUrl, String.class);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseStr);
    responseStr = jsonObject.getString("ethereum");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    CoingeckoPriceDTO result = mapper.readValue(responseStr, CoingeckoPriceDTO.class);

    result.setCoint(targetCurrency);

    return result;
}
```

I haven't run the code to see if it actually works, but you may make your adjustments if needed.

Comment: (I did some modifications just now)